# Deep learning with Imbalanced classes

Tags: neural-network, deep-learning, cnn, class-imbalance

I am trying to model a packet data with 1 dimensional CNN but I have a very imbalanced classes in my target. I have 3 classes as class 0 has 53000 cases, class 1 has 300 cases and class 2 has 150 cases. Thanks in advance!

I have tried what you have suggested but I do not think I am getting a good results(loss and accuracy), from the model.

[image]

Comment: Class imbalance is not a problem: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/357466/are-unbalanced-datasets-problematic-and-how-does-oversampling-purport-to-he. You are, however, quite low on data and probably don’t have enough to estimate the thousands or millions of parameters that will be in your neural network.

Comment: Thanks for answering!  I have added a picture of what i have done but i am not sure if it is right though.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using TensorFlow to write your architecture,

1. You can create 3 training datasets( one for one class) using `tf.data` and then you can use `tf.data.experimental.sample_from_datasets` with the same weightage to generate the batch data. Check `weights` parameter in the documentation.
2. You can initialize well in the final layer. Please check [this](http://karpathy.github.io/2019/04/25/recipe/) blog from Andrej Karpathy.
3. You can add the class_weight parameter while training.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have tried with class_weight parameter while training but the loss of the model is increasing instead of decreasing and my accuracy is held fixed by the model( it always gives me 99.60% Accuracy), i do not think that this method works to me or probably i am doing something else wrong. Can you ellaborate more what  you mean with creating a 3 training datasets(one for once class) using tf.data and then you can use tf.data.experimental.sample_from_datasets with the same weightage to generate the batch data...

Comment: I have added a picture of what i have done.